# [Solved]Conflict opencv different version cv_bridge and xfeatures2d

Tags: ros-melodic, cv-bridge

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone. I'm starting a project with OpenCV and i need to use xfeatures2d that is in opencv_contrib. I follow [this instructions](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-opencv-on-ubuntu-18-04/) and modify my CMake File in this way:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.2)
project(visual_odometry)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  cv_bridge
  image_transport
  roscpp
  rospy
  sensor_msgs
  nav_msgs
  geometry_msgs
  std_msgs
)

find_package(OpenCV 4 REQUIRED) 

catkin_package()

include_directories(
# include  
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

add_executable(show_image src/show_image.cpp)
target_link_libraries(show_image 
${catkin_LIBRARIES}
${OpenCV_LIBRARIES})

add_executable(show_video src/show_video.cpp)
target_link_libraries(show_video 
${catkin_LIBRARIES}
${OpenCV_LIBRARIES})

add_executable(visual_Odometry src/visual_Odometry.cpp)
target_link_libraries(visual_Odometry 
${catkin_LIBRARIES}
${OpenCV_LIBRARIES})
```

After `catkin_make` :

```
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libopencv_imgproc.so.4.5, needed by /usr/local/lib/libopencv_xfeatures2d.so.4.5.3, may conflict with libopencv_imgproc.so.3.2
```

During run time, some functions of imgproc like CLAHE algorithm doesn't work and my node stop to work.

When i build with catkin_make, cv_bridge find opencv3.2 default in ros, but my node find opencv4 thanks to CMake file. So, can I fix this?  It is possible build in opencv3.2 a opencv_contrib? It is possibile to change the version of opencv in cv_bridge?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/382266/%5Bsolved%5Dconflict-opencv-different-version-cv_bridge-and-xfeatures2d/) by [Elektron97](https://answers.ros.org/users/72984/elektron97/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2021-07-12

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Elektron97](https://answers.ros.org/users/72984/elektron97/) on 2021-07-14**:
Add some new informations for my problem! Hope is useful!

**Comment by [Elektron97](https://answers.ros.org/users/72984/elektron97/) on 2021-11-26**:
Please, answer me! I don't know how to fix this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found a solution in Github:

In catkin_ws/src:

```
git clone https://github.com/fizyr-forks/vision_opencv/tree/opencv4
cd vision_opencv
git checkout opencv4
```

---

Originally posted by [Elektron97](https://answers.ros.org/users/72984/elektron97/) with karma: 11 on 2021-11-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0